# Set Ag-Grid hight dynamically using Angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am using Ag-Grid.

Grid id is hiding the data little bit as below.

[image]

Below is my angular code for the same.

```
 <ag-grid-angular
            style="margin-top:10px;"
            class="ag-theme-balham"
            [pagination]="false"
            [rowData]="data"
            [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
            [pinnedBottomRowData]="pinnedBottomRowData"
            [pinnedTopRowData]="pinnedTopRowData"
            [getRowStyle]="getRowStyle"
            (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
            [headerHeight] = "headerHeight"
            [domLayout]="domLayout"           
            (rowClicked)="onRowClicked($event)" enableCellTextSelection=true>
        </ag-grid-angular>
```

After removing height from 1 div, grid is looking fine.

[image]

How to handle this situation dynamically ??

Comment: I'm really not sure what you mean.  Please could you provide a StackBlitz or similar?